# Why does the date format function return incorrect answer?

Tags: javascript

I need to format date. I use function **Intl.DateTimeFormat** but I don't understand why it does not format correctly **fTime**

Example:

```js
const date = new Date()
console.log('Date:', date)

const dateOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }
const timeOptions = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false }

const fDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(dateOptions).format(date)
const fTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(timeOptions).format(date)
console.log('fDate:', fDate)
console.log('fTime:', fTime)
```

I'm expecting to get an answer like this ( in my case such 20:10:25 )
[image]

Comment: It might help if you used the arguments the same way they're used in the expected case: `('locale', options)`, not just `(options)`.

Comment: @deceze But if I look doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat the locales is optional argument.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to pass either `locales` nor `options`. But Javascript parameters are positional and rarely can you pass an argument to a different parameter position. If you want to skip `locales`, try passing `undefined` for it instead.

Comment: But it work correctly with locales

Comment: Can you express your answer as the problem solution, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the options to the `locales` parameter. Even if `locales` is *optional*, it just means you don't need to supply a value for it; it doesn't mean you can try to skip it. If you don't want to supply a value for `locales` but for `options`, pass `undefined` instead:

```js
const date = new Date()
console.log('Date:', date)

const dateOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }
const timeOptions = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false }

const fDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, dateOptions).format(date)
const fTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, timeOptions).format(date)
console.log('fDate:', fDate)
console.log('fTime:', fTime)
```